# Is it correct to say "place the the yogurt box's lid face-down on the table"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Look at the picture,

What is the piece that people stick on top of the yogurt box to cover the top called, for example, "**the yogurt box's lid**"?

And look at "**the lid**", the side that faces the yogurt is called the face or the bottom of the lid.

Some yogurt might stick to this side and I don't want my child to put the lid on the table with this side coming in contact with the table because it will make the table dirty.

Is it correct to say "**place the the yogurt box's lid face-down on the table**"?

Comment: Native speakers would almost ***never*** use the possessive here. We'd just use "yoghurt box" as a ***noun adjunct*** (noun used adjectivally) modifying the "head" noun ***lid***, as *Place the the yogurt box lid face-down on the table*. Other than that your example is perfectly idiomatic (except that when speaking to a *child*, we'd nearly all choose to use the verb ***put*** rather than ***place***, which is a bit "formal" here).

Comment: I would call it a yoghurt **pot** and the foil the **top** (I think of a lid as something that you can take off and put on again). I wouldn't use the term **face** of something like that - I would probably say **"Don't put the foil on the table sticky side down."**

Comment: I'd call it a yogurt cup. (USA). In the quart size I buy, there would be a separate plastic lid to put back on the cup after the foil is removed, to protect the uneaten contents.

Comment: You're overcomplicating things again, Tom.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I'd call it a yogurt **pot**. Strangely, I have just discovered that 'yoghurt' is supposed to be the dominant spelling in the UK, which is news to me. When it first started being a mainstream product in the UK in the 1970s, you saw yogurt, yoghurt, yogourt, or yoghourt on product labelling, but yogurt seems to be pretty common now. I have a pot thus labelled in my fridge.

Comment: "Lid" refers to stiff coverings, like on garbage cans, pots, jars, or disposable coffee cups,  not to flexible things like the foil here. There's no standard term for it, but most people would understand "foil top", "foil seal" or "foil covering"

Answer (score 1):

I see one significant problem. For some objects, "face-up" has a clear and determined meaning—playing cards, for instance. But unless there's a regional usage that makes it clear to you but not to me, I don't know that it's a given that the yogurt-y side of the "lid" is the "face," so "face-up" could mean either orientation.

The best improvement would be to simply specify exactly what you mean:

> Place the yogurt lid on the table, dirty side up.

Comment: You'll note I skirted the issue of what you call the container (not explicitly identified as a part of the question. I suspect that there might be regional variations around cup/pot/box (?). But I used one more option: In my house we often refer to it by the trick that renders uncountable nouns countable: "Dad, can I have a yogurt?"